# Bitbucket tag automatically create version file?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-tag

I'm getting ready to release the first version of an electron app I made that we will be sending to some clients. We are storing our project in BitBucket Cloud and once we are ready to send them the app I'm going to tag in BitBucket.

I see that BitBucket supports annotated tags such as adding the version number like "v1.0.1" and that makes me curious if there's a way to have it auto create/update a version file on tagging, maybe with the use of hooks? This way I can have node read the file and display it in the app. Currently we just have the version in the app.js file but with this we have to remember to update it before we tag the commit. Or possibly is this information stored somewhere in the .git folder that I could use a gulp task to grab it before it builds the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unaware that npm has semantic versioning built into it which does just what I'm looking for!

https://travishorn.com/semantic-versioning-with-git-tags-1ef2d4aeede6

The following commands can be used to update the package version:

```
npm version patch
npm version minor
npm version major
```

That will update the package.json version which can be loaded in the node application with:

```
app.getVersion();
```

Also this creates a git tag which can be pushed with the following command:

```
git push origin master --follow-tags
```